# Creating projects based on jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, deployment, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, projects

Having learned to program in Python with Jupyter Notebooks, I've found this to be a very practical way of analyzing data, writing simple programs and even interacting with databases.

However, if one is working on a bigger project (with program and database that run automatically and should also eventually be deployed), is it still possible / reasonable to run the code from Notebooks? If so, do you have any advice on that?

Otherwise, I would of course resort to an IDE. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jupyter Notebooks are awesome tools, and great for certain types of collaborative development, and creating interactive web apps.

The purpose of Jupyter Notebooks is to provide a framework for combining rich text elements and code together (perfect for data science projects, tutorials or interactive dashboards). Jupyter notebooks also allow you to run code in multiple languages, which is a neat feature if your project requires it.

You probably wouldn't want to run a large scale production application from a Jupyter notebook, but you could certainly use them to help you develop it.

Check out this presentation for using Jupyter notebooks with multiple users.
https://www.slideshare.net/mbussonn/jupyter-a-platform-for-data-science-at-scale

If you specified the type of project you were considering it might be easier to suggest alternatives to help complete it.